# Rails Controller action render last page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to redirect to page from where I come is that possible?

What I do:

Calling a controller function from an view, and when action is finished I want to render the same page like a back function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
redirect_to :back
```

You can also pass more params to it. Read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: when using a redirect, validation errors associated to the resource are not preserved, so this is not a perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is actually render (not redirect) to the last rendered view you can do it in the following way:

```rb
render request.referer.split('/').last
```

It guesses the last rendered view from the request HTTP referer (the URL from which the controller action has been called). Note this approach it's quite fragile, but can be handy in most cases.